# Return 5 elements for for each type with aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How do I create an aggregate operation that shows me 5 for each **type**?
For example, what I need is to show 5 of `type= 1` , 5 of `type=2` and 5 of `type=3`.

I have tried:

```
db.items.aggregate([
    {$match : { "type" : { $gte:1,$lte:3 }}},
    {$project: { "type": 1, "subtipo": 1, "dateupdate": 1, "latide": 1, "long": 1, "view": 1,month: { $month: "$dateupdate" } }},
    {$sort:{view: -1, dateupdate: -1}},
    {$limit:5}
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline, you need to do an initial group which creates an array of the original documents. After that you can **[`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/#exp._S_slice)** the array with the documents to return the 5 elements.

The intuition can be followed in this example:

```
db.items.aggregate([
    { '$match' : { 'type': { '$gte': 1, '$lte': 3 } } },
    {       
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$type',
            'docs': { '$push': '$$ROOT' },
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            'five_docs': { 
                '$slice': ['$docs', 5]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

---

The above will return the 5 documents unsorted in an array. If you need to return the TOP 5 documents in sorted order then you can introduce a **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline before grouping the docs that re-orders the documents getting into the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline by the `type` and `dateupdate` fields:

```
db.items.aggregate([
    { '$match' : { 'type': { '$gte': 1, '$lte': 3 } } },
    { '$sort': { 'type': 1, 'dateupdate': -1 } }, // <-- re-order here
    {       
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$type',
            'docs': { '$push': '$$ROOT' },
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            'top_five': { 
                '$slice': ['$docs', 5]
            }
        }
    }
])
```